# GLSL: Access to implicitly-sized array with function parameter

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have the following code segment in a GLSL 4.0 core geometry shader:

```
void pushVertex(const int i)
{
    gl_Position = gl_in[i].gl_Position;
    // Some other stuff
    EmitVertex();
}
```

Later I basically call `pushVertex(0); pushVertex(1);` and so on.

This actually works on Windows with Nvidia drivers, however MaxOSX throws the error *Indirect index into implicitly-sized array*. Any ideas on a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to convince the GLSL compiler to inline this function so that the index becomes a constant, and indirect indexing isn't needed.  Since the compiler apparently doesn't do it for you, you could try defining `pushVertex` as a macro:

```
#define pushVertex(I) if(1) {              \
    gl_Position = gl_in[I].gl_Position;    \
    /* other stuff */                      \
    EmitVertex();                          \
} else
```

Of course, if the compiler is so weak that it can't inline, it may have trouble with the macro.

Comment: Yeah I solved it with a macro. I actually didn't know that GLSL supports macros to the extent of the C preprocessor. You might want to remove the trailing `else` though.

Comment: Oh okay, but wouldn't it work without the else? Wouldn't it also work without the if and just with curly braces?

Comment: Sure, as long as you don't try to use it like `if (p) pushVertex(1); else pushVertex(2);`

Comment: Oh I see. That is also the reason why people do it with do-while: `#define doSomething(...) do {...} while(0)`. Honestly I think that is less confusing than the trailing else statement. Also: Macro programming has so many pitfalls that even I with now 10 years of C++ experience just learned something :D

Comment: The problem with do..while is that it's more likely to break from failing to optimize properly on a broken GLSL compiler that can't inline properly...